# How to add data from multiple models to HTML template - Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

**Background**

I have created an small app that can add projects, and show it in the index page, all those projects can be access individualy to its own "profile proJect page" clicking on the project name.

Inside the project's profile page, it can be seeing data as `ProjectName`, `ResponsableName`, `Description` and so on.

**Problem**

I would like to fetch data from different tables to `projects profile page` until now I can only retrieve data from project table, but not from the rest of them, How could archive that ?

**views.py**

```
def registro(request, proyecto_id):
    proyecto = Proyecto.objects.get(pk=proyecto_id)
    return render (request, "Portafolio/registro.html", {
        'proyectos': proyecto
    })
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Proyecto(models.Model):
    NombreProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ResponsableProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    EvaluadorProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    DescripcionProyecto = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Financiamiento(models.Model):
    MontoProyecto = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    MontoPropio = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    MontoBanca = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    MontoPublico = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    proyecto = models.OneToOneField(Proyecto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=False, null=True)

class Beneficio(models.Model):
    Rentabilidad = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    proyecto = models.OneToOneField(Proyecto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=False, null=True)


class Infraestructura(models.Model):
    Infraestructura= models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    Tiempo = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Costo = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=False, null=True)


class Herramienta(models.Model):
    Herramienta= models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    Cantidad = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Costo = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=False, null=True)


class Equipo(models.Model):
    Personal = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    Cantidad = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Duracion = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Costo = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=False, null=True)


class Recurso(models.Model):
    materia_prima = models.CharField(max_length= 64)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    valor_unitario = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=False, null=True)
```

**registro.html**

```
{% extends "Portafolio/layout.html" %}


{% block content %}

<h1>Proyecto {{proyectos.NombreProyecto}}</h1>
<h2>Detalle del Proyecto</h2>

<fieldset>
    <ul>
        <li>Responsable proyecto: {{proyectos.ResponsableProyecto}}</li>
        <li>Evaluador proyecto: {{proyectos.EvaluadoProyecto}}</li>
        <li>Descripción Proyecto: {{proyectos.DescripcionProyecto}}</li>
    </ul>
<fieldset>
<hr>

<h2>1.Factibilidad Financiera</h2>
<h3>A) Financiamiento </h3>

<fieldset>
    <ul>

    </ul>
<fieldset>
<hr>

<h3>B) Beneficio </h3>
<fieldset>
    <ul>

    </ul>
    <input class= "btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="submit" value="Agregar Información">
<fieldset>

<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Volver a Inicio</a>

{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE 1**
I have made the following changes as it was request in the answer section, but it still doesn't retrieve data as expected

```
def registro(request, proyecto_id):
    proyecto = Proyecto.objects.get(pk=proyecto_id)

    financiamento = Financiamiento.objects.filter(proyecto = proyecto)
    beneficio = Beneficio.objects.filter(proyecto = proyecto)


    return render (request, "Portafolio/registro.html", {
        'proyectos': proyecto,
        'financiamentos':financiamento,
        'benwficios': beneficio,       

    })
```

**registro.html (updated)**

```
{% extends "Portafolio/layout.html" %}


{% block content %}

<h1>Proyecto {{proyectos.NombreProyecto}}</h1>
<h2>Detalle del Proyecto</h2>

<fieldset>
    <ul>
        <li>Responsable proyecto: {{proyectos.ResponsableProyecto}}</li>
        <li>Evaluador proyecto: {{proyectos.EvaluadorProyecto}}</li>
        <li>Descripción Proyecto: {{proyectos.DescripcionProyecto}}</li>
        <li>Monto: {{financiamento.MontoProyecto}}</li>
    </ul>

</fieldset>
<hr>

<h2>1.Factibilidad Financiera</h2>
<h3>A) Financiamiento </h3>

<fieldset>
    <ul>
        <li>Monto: {{financiamentos.MontoProyecto}}</li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<hr>

<fieldset>
    <ul>
        <li>Monto: {{benwficios.Rentabilidad}}</li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<hr>

<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Volver a Inicio</a>

{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE 2** I could solve it through for loop, it is not the most elegant solution, but it do its job. let me know if there's a better way to do this.

Example:

```
<fieldset>
    <ul> 
            {% for i in financiamentos %}   
                <li>Monto: {{i.MontoProyecto}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have added ForeignKey and OnetoOne field with Proyecto model with every other models.

If you want to render the other models, you can use filter by proyecto in views function.

```
def registro(request, proyecto_id):
    proyecto = Proyecto.objects.get(pk=proyecto_id)

    ##### HERE ADD MODELS LOGIC################
    financiamento = Financiamento.objects.filter(proyecto = proyecto)
    benwficio = Beneficio.objects.filter(proyecto = proyecto)

    ... and so on do this with all the remaining models


   ################################################################

    return render (request, "Portafolio/registro.html", {
        'proyectos': proyecto,
        'financiamento':financiamento,
        ... so on...
    })
```

and add the contexts to html templates.

Comment: Answer Check: The solution provide doesn't work, anyway I have updated the question with the solution provided